# Java - get parent object from child object

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I am trying to get base object from parent object but i am not able to.
Do we have anything like this?`

```
public class A
{
}

public class B extends A
{
    A obj = this.getParentObject();     
}
```

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html Although it seems rather hacky what you're trying to do now. A subclass shouldn't hold a reference to the baseclass, that doesn't even make sense.

Comment: My A class is Entity class in hibernate. I don't want to write any functions in my entity class but i want entity object in child class for inserting.

Comment: There is no such thing as a *parent object*. Java uses class-based inheritance.

Comment: if you have `B b = new B();` you can get the parent A by default casting Java provides. `A a = (A)b` This is automatic, so just writing `A a = b` will have the same result.

Answer (score 4):

You should read how the **[super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)** keyword and **[inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)** works in Java.

Getting the **superclass**, or the class your class extends, is not really necessary in the general case. See the below illustration:

```
public class A {

    protected int value;

    public A() {
        this.value = 2;
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        System.out.println(value); // prints 2
    }

}
```

To refer to the superclass, use the **super** keyword. See example below:

```
public class A {

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        doStuff(); // prints "child"
        super.doStuff(); // prints "parent"
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }

}
```

I hope this answers your question.

---

**The hacky and generally unneccessary stuff**

You CAN, of course, get the parent object. For this I recommend making a protected (or public) method for the class A that returns itself. See code example below:

```
public class A {

    protected A getMe() {
        return this;
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    public B() {
        A superInstance = getMe();
    }

}
```

This is untested code, but I can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Of course this last idea cannot be correct. In method getMe() called from B's constructor, this refers to the B instance being created. Not to any A instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing. You instantiate an object from class B, which extends A. It's just one object, does not "contain" A inside it. Let's say A has also other properties:

```
public class A
{
  public int a;
}

public class B extends A
{
  public int b;
}
```

Objects from class B will have both attributes a and b.

With "super" keyword you can access the methods from the base class. But you can't "get the object" from the base class.